# Swift: convert string into integer

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, int

I'm getting JSON data with different data types.
I want to convert a string '22' into integer 22.

I have this code: `jData["ID"]`

I have tried:
     `let id = jData["ID"]! as Int`

but it gave me an error

EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT,subcode=0xdefe)

Can someone please solve my problem...

Thanks

Comment: `let id = ((jData["ID"] as? String) ?? "0").toInt() ?? 0`

Comment: YESS this one worked, Thanks @vacawama

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `jData["ID"]` as string and use [`toInt()`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH7-SW19):

```
let id = String(jData["ID"]).toInt()
```

Comment: I'v tried that it gives me error: 'AnyObject' does not have a member named 'toInt()'